# Tshark custom grep

Tags: linux, grep, tshark

So my command is:

```
tshark -Y 'wlan.fc.type_subtype==0x04'
```

So my output is:

```
21401 205.735966 Apple_90:ea:8e -> Broadcast    802.11 155 Probe Request, SN=3667, FN=0, Flags=........C, SSID=Broadcast
```

How can I get Apple_90:ea:8e + SSID=Broadcast and whats the logic behind the grep? Is it possible with grep?

Considering that:  Apple_90:ea:8e and Broadcast will always change!

Comment: So `Apple_90:ea:8e` and `SSID=` will always be the same and you want to know what `Broadcast` is, or what does change and what do you want exactly?

Comment: No the "Apple_90:ea:8e" and "Broadcast" will always change.

Comment: So, you want the third space separated field? Something with two colons? The thing before `->`? You don't give us much to work with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102012/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-dvvcnxc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ var='21401 205.735966 Apple_90:ea:8e -> Broadcast    802.11 155 Probe Request, SN=3667, FN=0, Flags=........C, SSID=Broadcast'
$ grep -oP '\S+(?= ->)|SSID=\S+' <<< "$var"
Apple_90:ea:8e
SSID=Broadcast
```

The grep option `-o` says "only return what was matched, not the whole line" and `-P` is to use the Perl regex engine (because we use look-arounds). The regex is

```
\S+       # One or more non-spaces
(?= ->)   # followed by " ->"
|         # or...
SSID=\S+  # "SSID=" and one or more non-spaces
```